# iOS app loads html , can I change the url prefix

Tags: ios, cocos2d-html5

I just took over the company's app, the app needs to load html to play a cocos2d-html5 game. Loading the index.html and the url prefix of **index.html** is `file:///`, but the code contains a judgment, if the url prefix contains `negame://` then some methods can response, so  can I change the prefix into `negame://`

Comment: Are you using UIWebView?

Comment: I'm glad that you resolved it. I guess you could post your solution and mark that as the accepted answer so others in the future will benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is not a question, because i mistook that the prefix url of index.html need to change into 'negame://',actually, There are a lot of buttons in the game, clicking on the buttons will pass the url, some of the urls contain 'negame://'...